# JavaScript callback values not correctly passed

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, callback

I am having some trouble passing a constant value to a callback function. I am performing a *RESTful* request using `ajax`, then handling the *error* and *success* events by returning data to a callback that inserts a constant as the first argument (SUCCESS or ERROR), and returns it to yet another callback listener. The only issue is that these newly-added, first-arguments are not added correctly (or even at all). I have added notes in the code where my errors are. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhDBrown/QuaC6/1/).

```
(function( REST, $, undefined) 
{

    REST.get = function(_url, _data, _onSuccessCallback, _onErrorCallback)
    {
        console.log("GET");

        $.ajax({
            type:       'GET',
            url:        _url,
            data:       _data,
            dataType:   'json',
            headers:    {contentType: 'application/json'},
            success:    _onSuccessCallback,
            error:      _onErrorCallback
        });

    };
}
(window.REST = window.REST || {}, jQuery));


(function( DSP, $, undefined) 
{
    var baseURL = "www.example.com";

    /** The request was successful */
    DSP.SUCCESS = 0;
    /** The request failed */
    DSP.ERROR = 1;

    DSP.get = function(url, _data, callback)
    {
        REST.get(url, 
                _data, 
                function(data, text)
                { 
                    console.log("Success. arg0 = " + DSP.SUCCESS);
                    callback.call(DSP.SUCCESS, data, text);
                },
                function(request, status, error)
                {
                    //So far, it's just errors. 
                    console.log("\nError. arg0 = " + DSP.ERROR);//This prints "Error. arg0 = 1"
                    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
                    {
                        console.log(arguments[i]);//prints the request Object and the text "error"
                    }
                    callback.call(DSP.ERROR, request, status, error);//doesn't seem to correctly insert the ERROR constant.
                }
        );
    };


    DSP.getSomething = function(callback) 
    {
        console.log("Get something");
        var url = baseURL + "/Something";
        DSP.get(url, null, function(){
            console.log("ARGUMENTS LENGTH = " + arguments.length);//prints 3
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(arguments[i].toString());//prints all same Objects as above
            }
            if (arguments.length < 1) {
                console.error("error in request");
                callback.call(null);
            }
            if (arguments[0] == DSP.ERROR)//should get to here. Why doesn't it???
            {
                var request = arguments[1];
                var status = arguments[2];
                var error = arguments[3];
                console.error("Failed To Get Something (" + request.responseText + ")");
                callback.call(null);
            }
            else if (arguments[0] == DSP.SUCCESS)
            {
                var data = arguments[1];
                var text = arguments[2];

                callback.call(data);
            }
            else
            {
                //gets to this line and prints "arguments[0] ([object Object]) != SUCCESS(0) !=ERROR(1)."
                console.log("arguments[0] (" + arguments[0].toString() + ") != SUCCESS(" + DSP.SUCCESS + ") != ERROR(" + DSP.ERROR + ").");
                console.error("internal error");
                callback.call(null);
            }
        });
    };
}
(window.DSP = window.DSP || {}, jQuery));

window.DSP.getSomething(function(response){
    if (!response)
    {
        //this is printed.
        console.log("error. No user returned.")
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("RESPONSE: " + response.toString());
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? The error in `REST` should cause `DSP.get` to place the `DSP.ERROR` parameter as the first argument, and this should be handled by `getSomething`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
callback.call(DSP.ERROR, request, status, error);
```

to this:

```
callback(DSP.ERROR, request, status, error);
```

When you use `.call()` to invoke a function, the first argument to `.call()` sets the `this` value of the function you're invoking. The second argument to `.call()` sets the first argument of the function, and so on...

---

Same goes for:

```
callback/*.call*/(DSP.SUCCESS, data, text);
```

---

Also these:

```
callback/*.call*/(null);
callback/*.call*/(data);
```

Since your callback seems to anticipate receiving the data as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you! This saves me a lot of useless debugging!